# Characterization of continuous functions with the property $f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, functional-equations

Determine all the real valued functions $f$ defined on set of reals satisfying:

1. $f$ is continuous at $0$, and
2. $f(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ for all $x$ other than $1$.

Tried but don't know how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by induction that $f(x)=f(\frac x {1-nx})$. Let $n \to \infty$ to conclude that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x \neq  1,\frac 1  2,\frac  1 3,...$. You can also check that $f(\frac  1n )=f(\frac  1{n-1})$ for $n >1$. What do you conclude from this now?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $f$ is a constant. If you assume that the equation holds for $n$ then, writing $y$ for $\frac x {1-nx}$ we get  $f(x)=f(y)=f(\frac  y {1-y})$. Now calculate $\frac  y {1-y}$. Very simple high school algebra will tell you that the equation holds for $n+1$.